# How to display months in Swedish?

Tags: wordpress, date, loops, blogs

If I use the following in WordPress, I get the month in English, but I want it in Swedish, for instance "maj" instead of "may". Can I get dates in Swedish?

```
the_time('j F Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

Rascal,

To localize dates, use the date_i18n() function.

You need also to use .po for the Swedish language. See the file .po for the french language.

http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress-i18n/fr_FR/tags/2.0.11/messages/fr_FR.po

Search for the swedish language in url:

http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress-i18n/

Comment: can you describe process how to use .po files?
BTW here is the url of Swedish Language http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress-i18n/sv_SE/tags/3.6.1/messages/sv_SE.po